# GKE public endpoint - will it change?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I have a GKE cluster that has a public IP for the master. For example, when I run `gcloud container clusters describe`, I see a line like below:

```
publicEndpoint: 34.68.128.12
```

Questions:

1. Does the public IP change arbitrarily?
2. If the answer is Yes, can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe public endpoints on GKE are immutable, so it will not change.

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation that says yes or no. Have you come across any?

Comment: when u go to cluser details if you bring your cursor on the lock, It will say ip is immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you delete and create the cluster again. The Public IP doesn't change